# how to modify signature of PEM formatted certificate in python

Tags: python, certificate, x509, signature, pem

Is there a way modify the signature of a PEM encoded x509 certificate with python?

I've tried using the cryptography python module but it seems the x509 signature atrribute is not settable. I can only get its value. Is there another python module that might work better for this purpose?

The cryptography python module documentation is here:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-certificate-object

```py
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding
import os

#change the signature of the cert
def change_cert_sig(pem_data):
    cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
    #the line below works
    print(cert.signature)
    #the line below causes an exception "AttributeError: can't set attribute"
    cert.set_signature(os.urandom(len(cert.signature))) #set signature to random bytes
    return cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way modify the signature of a PEM encoded x509 certificate with python?

Yes.

I'm not a Python guy, so I can only describe what to do... Read the certificate into memory. Here is the ASN.1 structure of the certificate from [RFC 5280, Appendix A, p. 116 (and friends)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280):

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
     signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
     signature            BIT STRING  }
```

`tbsCertificate` is what the Issuer (or certificate authority) signs. *"TBS"* means *"to be signed."* `signature` is the issuer's signature over `tbsCertificate`. And `signatureAlgorithm` describes the signing algorithm used, like `sha256WithRSAEncryption`.

Skip to the third attribute, which is the one `signature   BIT STRING`. The first 4 octets are part of the ASN.1 encoding for a `BIT_STRING`. Octets 5-37 are the signature bytes. Take one of the signature bytes and tamper with it. Something like `Byte b = data[6]`, `b ^= 0x01` and then `data[6] = b`.

Since `signature` is the very last thing in the certificate, you should be able to tamper with any of the last 32 bytes in the file. The last 32 bytes are the signature. (32 bytes assumes a signature using SHA-256).

Comment: Not related to answer, and sorry if I'm too curious, but how did you end up in Penalty Box?

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial.

You're calling `cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM)`, which has following source code:

```
def public_bytes(self, encoding):
    bio = self._backend._create_mem_bio_gc()
    if encoding is serialization.Encoding.PEM:
        res = self._backend._lib.PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, self._x509)
    elif encoding is serialization.Encoding.DER:
        res = self._backend._lib.i2d_X509_bio(bio, self._x509)
    else:
        raise TypeError("encoding must be an item from the Encoding enum")

    self._backend.openssl_assert(res == 1)
    return self._backend._read_mem_bio(bio)
```

That goes to `PEM_write_bio_X509` which is actually implemented in C and accessed through CFFI.

The  argument passed to it, `._x509` is just a data blob:

```
In [25]: c._x509
Out[25]: <cdata 'X509 *' 0x7f8608d08890>
```

This means that to modify the signature in the existing object, you'd have to find the memory location and overwrite that memory location...

Which would be quite so wrong.

You see, `cryptography` is a thin shim over underlying library, like OpenSSL. It does not, by default, give you out all the details. The right way would be to decompose the X.509 representation of your certificate into a bunch of fields, then add, remove, modify these fields and then roll this back into X.509.

However, since that's just too hard, watch this:

```
pd  # PEM data as a string
'-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIC [snip] 1Q=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n'

b64 = "".join([bit for bit in pd.split() if "---" not in bit])
pemdata = binascii.a2b_base64(b64)

cert.signature in pemdata
True
```

So, it just happens that certificate signature is occupies a range of bytes in the cert blob, so, let's try to change it:

```
pemdata.find(cert.signature)
423
len(cert.signature)
128
fakesig = b"\x42" * len(cert.signature)
fakecertdata = pemdata[:423] + fakesig + pemdata[423 + 128:]
with open("fake.pem", "wb") as fout:
    fout.write(b"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n")
    fout.write(base64.encodebytes(fakecertdata))
    fout.write(b"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n")
```

Lo and behold!

```
> openssl x509 -in fake.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: [snip]
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: [snip]
        Validity [snip]
        Subject: [snip]
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00: [snip] :55
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:42:
         42:42
```

Comment: Isn't the signature ASN.1 encoded? I think that, depending on the actual signature data, some further modifications are required.

Comment: YMMV, methinks that signature is whole number of bytes, at least for common algorithms, and DER encoding of ASN.1 encodes bytes as bytes. Thus, if the signature algorithm remains the same, then algorithm code doesn't need to be changed; signature length remains the same, then replacing the that sequence of bytes should be just fine. Base64 part of PEM needs to be unpacked and repacked, ofc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding

Comment: For P-256 elliptic curve it's kind of a mess as the signature contains ASN.1 Integers that might or might not get trimmed according to their value. More on this in Section 3.2 of [Compressed Certificate Definition](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-8974-CryptoAuth-ATECC-Compressed-Certificate-Definition-ApplicationNote.pdf) from Atmel.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the signature algorithm, the answer from [@Dima Tisnek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055753/1584915) might not always work. For example, elliptic curve P-256 signatures contain ASN.1 integers that might or might not get trimmed according to their value.

Here is a modified version that adjust the bit string and sequence length of the ASN.1 structure:

```py
cert_der = cert.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER)

assert(cert.signature in cert_der)

# see 3.2 Signature Reconstruction in Compressed Certificate Definition
sig_offset = cert_der.find(cert.signature)  
cert_der = bytearray(cert_der[:sig_offset] + signature)
cert_der[2:4] = (len(cert_der) - 4).to_bytes(2, 'big')
cert_der[sig_offset-2] = len(signature) + 1
cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert_der)
```

A detailed explanation of the required modifications is explained in Section 3.2 of [Compressed Certificate Definition](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-8974-CryptoAuth-ATECC-Compressed-Certificate-Definition-ApplicationNote.pdf) from Microchip/Atmel.